# Nested model and polymorphic associations in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an application with three models - Offer, OfferType and Category. A category has many offers, an offertype has many offers, and an offer belongs to a category and an offer type. I am trying to make a form for making a new offer with a description (a field in the Offer model), radio buttons for offertypes and a dropdown for categories using the Simple Form gem.

Currently I have tried to implement polymorphic associations based on [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) RailsCast. I figured this would let me filter offers by category and offertype. I'm also wondering if it might be a good idea to use "accepts_nested_attributes_for" to nest the models to make it accessible in the form?

I'm having trouble with my controllers and I was wondering if this is still a good way to approach the problem. I've included my code below.

**Offer Model:**

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :offerable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**OfferType Model:**

```
class OfferType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :offers, as: :offerable
end
```

**Offers Controller:**

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :offer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_filter :load_offerable

    def index
        @offer = @offerable.offers
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @offer = @offerable.offers.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
        @offer = @offerable.offers.new(offer_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @offer.save
                format.html { redirect_to @offerable, notice: "Offer was created successfully." }
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @offer }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @offer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @offerable.offers.update(offer_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @offerable, notice: "Offer was created successfully." }
                format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @offerable.offers.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @offerable.offers.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to offer_url }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private

    def set_offer
        @offer = @offerable.offers.find(params[:id])
    end

    def offer_params
        params.require(:offer).permit(:description)
    end

    def load_offerable
        resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
        @offerable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    end

end
```

**OfferTypes Controller:**

```
class OfferTypesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_offer_type, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @offer_type = OfferType.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @offer_type = OfferType.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
        @offer_type = OfferType.new(offer_type_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @offer_type.save
                format.html { redirect_to @offer_type, notice: "Offer Type was successfully created." }
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @offer_type }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'new' }
                format.json { render json: @offer_type.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @offer_type.update(offer_type_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @offer_type, notice: "Offer Type was successfully updated." }
                format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: 'edit' }
                format.json { render json: @offer_type.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @offer_type.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to offer_types_url }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end

    private

    def set_offer_type
        @offer_type = OfferType.find(params[:id])
    end

    def offer_type_params
        params.require(:offer_type).permit(:name)
    end
end
```